# Getting PHP and MySQL Setup for user login page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to create a login page so that certain users within our organization will have access to a form with sensitive information. I decided to use PHP and MySQL to do this and believe I am very close, but am having issues getting the two to connect to one another. I am using WAMP server so I have a localhost setup.

Here is my very basic html form:

```
<form method="post" action="addemail.php">
   <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /> <br/>
   <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /> <br/>
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /> <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

On my PHP form, I have this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'leadmen') 
or die('Error connection to MySQL server.');

$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query ="INSERT INTO leadmen_usernames (first_name, last_name, email)" .
"VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database');

echo 'Username Added.';

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I don't know too much about these technologies but believe the problem lies either within my connection info to $dbc = mysqli_connect, or maybe there's an error with mysqli vs mysql?

Not sure if this matters, but I used phpmyadmin to create the table.

Comment: When I submit the form, I get redirected to a white page that just shows the php content...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Try to remove the `" . "` your code seems to check out.

Comment: When I remove the period the code breaks in dreamweaver..

Comment: Try `$query ="INSERT INTO leadmen_usernames (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";` and check your column names.

Comment: Check your server if it runs php in another file...

Comment: "When I remove the period the code breaks in dreamweaver" => "INSERT INTO leadmen_usernames (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')". You have to remove the two quotation marks and put everything on one line then, too

Comment: Is PHP and SQL running? Do you already have a `.php` file that you know runs? I.e.: `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` (*I have to ask*)

Comment: Thanks again, column names match up but after putting this code in, it executes the same and replies a white page with the php code :/

Comment: Ah, there you go. PHP is either not installed or not setup properly, if you see actual code.

Comment: I've gotten php to work on my server and have created a separate form already which I have tested. I'm not positive that SQL is running but I don't know how to check that either... It says connected on wamp server and I was able to run phpmyadmin so I'm assuming its good...

Comment: Did you try running `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`?

Comment: I just created a new folder on my localhost and named it test. I included that echo statement in the document and when I load the test.php file on localhost, I get "Hello World" to show up. This means that PHP is in fact running correct?

Comment: Yes, that's a start. Now you need to check if SQL is installed and running.

Comment: Do you know an easy way to do this? I can't seem to find much about this online for some reason :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Google "wamp check if MySQL is loaded".

Comment: I figured out my issue. Everything was in place and working. The only thing I had to do was instead of going to localhost directly, use http://localhost instead. Not sure why this matters but its working now... Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

If you see just the PHP code you probably forgot the opening PHP tag before you start to write actual PHP code.

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'leadmen') 
or die('Error connection to MySQL server.');

$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query ="INSERT INTO leadmen_usernames (first_name, last_name, email)" .
"VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database');

echo 'Username Added.';

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

You can close it again with '?>'

Comment: Thanks but I have the opening and closing tags in place, just didn't think it was necessary to include them on here.

Comment: Are you sure your server is able to serve PHP files then? Have you set up a server or are you just using the HTML WYSISWYG editor / preview function of Dreamweaver?

Comment: I setup a wamp server and have been using php on that. When I test <?php echo "Hello world"; ?>, it runs fine. For some reason its just showing my entire php code when I submit this. I think my login information might be wrong but even if it was, I would expect an error rather than it just submitting the code. I'm totally lost now :/

Comment: Two last ideas: Are you using the short tags (<? instead of <?php) for your code? If so, they're deprecated and often disabled. If you you're not using them, how do you access your file? Make sure it's in your wamp's www folder and open it via http://localhost/path/to/file and not via file://path/to/www/and/file